# uiprogressview doesn't appear below uitableview in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiprogressview

I am writing a program that employs a UIProgressView that gets added programmatically  and hidden/revealed during program execution. I have the following code that worked in iOS 5.  The code adds the UIProgressView "below" a UITableView by adding the UIProgressView as a subview of the superview of the UITableView.  This also keeps the UIProgressView in one place while the UITableView scrolls.

In viewDidLoad, I set the frame of the UIProgressView

```
UIProgressView * progressBar = [[[UIProgressView alloc]    
initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar] retain];
progressBar.hidden = NO;
progressBar.progress = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"progress"];

//Set up the UIProgressView
frameForProgressBar = CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                 self.tableView.frame.origin.y +      
                                 self.tableView.frame.size.height -  
                                 progressBar.frame.size.height,
                                 self.tableView.frame.size.width,
                                 progressBar.frame.size.height);

progressBar.frame = frameForProgressBar;
insetsForTableView = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, progressBar.frame.size.height, 0.0, 0.0);
```

and then when I want the UIProgressView to appear

```
// Add the Progress bar to the Window
progressBarState = ADD_PROGRESS_BAR;
[self.view.superview addSubview:progressBar];
```

and  so that I can see the UIProgressView, I change the contentInsets of the UITableView.  To accommodate iOS 7, I read that changes to contentInsets must happen in viewWillLayoutSubviews.

```
-(void) viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    switch (progressBarState)
    {
        case ADD_PROGRESS_BAR:
            // Set the frame of the UITableView to allow the UIProgressView to appear
            self.tableView.contentInset = insetsForTableView;
            break;
        case REMOVE_PROGRESS_BAR:
            self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    progressBarState = UNDEFINED_PROGRESS_BAR;
}
```

I run this code through the debugger and viewWillLayoutSubviews does get called.  However, I don't see the UITableView resize and I don't see the UIProgressView.  I tried setting a frame for the UITableView to make it much smaller than the screen and then setting a frame for the UIProgressView that would have placed it in the "empty" space.  But, I was still unable to see the UIProgressView.

Can someone suggest why I can't see the UIProgressView?

Thanks,

Jason Mazzotta

Answer (score 0):

Set automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets property of UIViewController to NO.
Since this property is available for iOS 7 and later so check availability using respondToSelector method.

Comment: Hi dev gr.  Thanks for the reply.  I tried that and I don't see any change.

Comment: Where are you setting the property?

Comment: I managed to replace the UITableViewController with a UIViewController.  With a few changes, I can now see the UIProgressView update along with the contents of the table.  Thanks for all your help.